# Automating zip archive

Tags: powershell, zip, 7zip

So I am trying to process files in to separate  backup files, however the this craetes a single archive named as the last file in the array.  I am not sure what I am missing here.

```
$process = "C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe"
$destinationdir = "M:\WIP\OUT\"
$sourcedir = "M:\WIP\ZIP\"
$password = "password"
$ziplist = get-childitem $sourcedir
foreach ($zip in $ziplist)
{$destinationfile= $zip+".zip"
Start-Process $process -ArgumentList "a $destinationfile $zip -o$destinationdir    -p$password"-NoNewWindow -Wait
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```powershell
 $destinationfile= $zip+".zip"
```

to

```powershell
$destinationfile= $zip.FullName+".zip"
```